# need to extract entire node of xml file based on its child nodes attribute value

Tags: xml, vb.net

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tabel>
<Members>
  <Member>
    <Naam>Cruciatum</Naam>
    <Kills>1000</Kills>
    <Deaths>10</Deaths>
    <KD>100</KD>
  </Member>
  <Member>
    <Naam>Ghostbullet93</Naam>
    <Kills>10</Kills>
    <Deaths>1</Deaths>
    <KD>10</KD>
  </Member>
</Members>
</Tabel>
```

My question is that I want to extract entire member node where KD=10.Plz help me how to do it.
I am using vb.net as Programming language

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Linq to XML and `XDocument` class:

```
Dim xml = XDocument.Load("myFilePath")
' or xml = XDocument.Parse("<Tabel> (...) </Tabel>") '

Dim myMember = xml.Root
                  .Element("Members")
                  .Elements("Member")
                  .First(Function(m) CInt(m.Element("KD")) = 10)
```

After that, `myMember` would be an `XElement` class instance corresponding to `Member` element from XML.

Comment: Dear Marcin but I am not familair with linq could you give me example in vb.net or C#

Comment: That is VB.NET, isn't it?!

Comment: Marcin could you give me generalised example e.g if I have other tags nested in member  and those nested tags have have child nodes which has kd as attribut.

Comment: You should google for 'linq to xml tutorial'. There are plenty of them there!

Comment: Maybe I could, but I won't. Why? Because Linq to XML seems to be the best way here, and that's why my answer looks like it does.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples that you can look at.  If you really don't want to use LINQ, then you need to learn XPath.

```
Sub Main()

    'This method uses the Xml DOM in the System.Xml namespace with XPath
    Dim xmlDoc = New XmlDocument()

    xmlDoc.Load("c:\test\test.xml")

    Dim membersNode As XmlNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Tabel/Members")
    If membersNode IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim memberWithKDof10 As XmlNode = membersNode.SelectSingleNode("Member[KD = '10']")
        If memberWithKDof10 IsNot Nothing Then
            Console.WriteLine("Name of player with KD of 10 is {0}", memberWithKDof10.SelectSingleNode("Naam").InnerText)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Player not found!")
        End If
    End If


    'This method uses the XDocument classes found in the System.Xml.Linq namespace
    Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("c:\test\test.xml", LoadOptions.None)

    Dim membersElement As XElement = xDoc.Root.Element("Members")
    If membersElement IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim memberWithKDof10 As XElement = membersElement.Descendants("Member").FirstOrDefault(Function(e) e.Element("KD").Value = "10")
        If memberWithKDof10 IsNot Nothing Then
            Console.WriteLine("Name of player with KD of 10 is {0}", memberWithKDof10.Element("Naam").Value)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Player not found!")
        End If
    End If

    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit...")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```